# Is it possible to access selected object from the FormControl value in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I'm using reactive forms for validation, so when I want to submit the form I'm using the values from the FormControl instances. My template looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="status" formControlName="status">
    <option *ngFor="let status of statuses" [ngValue]="status">
        {{status.description}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Status object looks like this: `{ id: 1, description: "desc" }`

I would like to access to the whole status object with the value property of the `FormControl` (`this.form.controls.status.value`), but the selected string is stored in the value not the object.

I can access to the object when I subscribe to the valueChanges event. It seems a little bit illogical. I think I should get the same value when I subscribe to the value changes and when I access to the latest value by the property of the `FormControl`. It makes no sense to store the latest object in my component by subscribing to the value changes event, because that would force me to duplicate the value. I think this is the purpose of the form control. Maybe I do something wrong !? How can I make it work?

Comment: What do you mean "I would like to access to the whole status object"? By using `[ngValue]`, the `this.form.get('status').value` property should contain the selected status object, no?

Comment: you can only select one value, the value of object should be there.

Comment: @AngularFrance your solution worked. I don't understand then what is the difference between the this.form.get('status').value and what I used this.form.controls.status.value because the later one stores only the description of the status object.

Comment: The two syntaxes are more or less equivalent, but I believe the one you used is deprecated. It used to be the official syntax at the time of one of Angular's release candidates, but now the `FormGroup.get("controlName")` syntax is recommended to access individual form controls (to get their values or to check for errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My form was working fine in dev, but in prod it failed. If you use Ahead of time  compilation (AOT), then form.controls.controlName will fail. You have to use form.get(‘controlName’).

Don’t use control.errors?.someError, use control.hasError(‘someError’)

See this link for more details:

https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts

you can use the following to see the value of your form in your html:

```
form value: 
{{myForm.value | json}}
```